Unable to export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 on macOS?
When I execute locale -a on my Mac Book (macOS 14.4.1, Apple silicon), I can't find C.UTF-8 (though there are en_US.UTF-8, fr_FR.UTF-8, etc. And there are also C and POSIX, without specific encodings). At the same time, when I execute locale -a on my Ubuntu machine, I can find C.UTF-8.
Also on my Mac Book, the default locale is:
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

But after I execute export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8, the locale is
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL="C"

I just want to make sure when executing my shell script the encoding is UTF-8, because my script will calculate the length of a variable. But on my Mac Book, it seems that I can't add export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 at the beginning of my script?
(I know I can add export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 or export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 at the beginning, because I don't care the values of other LC_*. I just require LC_CTYPE to be UTF-8. But this workaround is not elegant IMO...)

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [apple.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

Possible cross-site duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384388/how-to-add-a-new-locale-to-macos-catalina

C.UTF-8 sounds like a weird locale name. AFIK, if you use the C locale, you can not have utf-8 with it; it is then simply C.

@user1934428 But I'm sure there is C.UTF-8 on my Ubuntu machine

You may be able to set the variable to this string, but AFIK, it has no well-defined effect. At best, it could communicate the intended encoding of strings, but this is already specified in the LANG variable. Do you have a concrete application whch relies on this setting, or are you asking this only out of curiosity?

One more point to consider perhaps (I'm not that proficient in locale issues): With locale -a I can see all installed locales on my Mac. There is no locale named C.UTF-8 amongst them. Hence, tryin to set it, has the same effect as setting LC_ALL=foo: It is not listed, and the net effect is that the C locale is used instead.

@user1934428 You are right. It indeed has the same effect as setting LC_ALL=foo. I've decided to keep the default as it already uses UTF-8 encoding.

Perhaps you can install the missing locale. See here. If this does not work, you really need to ask at [apple.se], whether it is possible, and how to do it.
